# d3 v4: Data join for bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to adopt bar chart example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714) to understand data joins in d3 v4. Enter selection works fine but I am unable to figure out how to update. Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/hackygkL/
Can someone please help me.

```
var width = 420,
    barheight = 30;

var svg = d3.select('#bar-chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + 50)
        .attr('height', 1000);



var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width]);


function createBar(data) {
    scale.domain([0, d3.max(data)]);
    var barGroups = svg.selectAll('g')
            .data(data, function(d){return d;});

    barGroups.exit().remove();

    var enterGroup = barGroups.enter() //ENTER
        .append('g')
        .merge(barGroups) //UPDATE
        .attr("transform", function(d, i){
            return "translate(0, " + barheight * i + ")";
        });

    var bars = barGroups.selectAll('rect');

    enterGroup.append('rect') //ENTER
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .attr('height', barheight - 1)
        .merge(bars) //UPDATE
        .attr('width', function(d){
            return scale(d);
        })
        .attr('fill', 'steelblue');

    var texts = barGroups.selectAll('text');

    enterGroup.append("text") //ENTER
        .attr('class', 'text')
        .attr("y", barheight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .merge(texts) //UPDATE
        .attr("x", function(d) { return scale(d) + 10; })
        .text(function(d) { return d;});
}
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to update the chart with new data. Can you please check the fiddle which demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work after merging the groups first, then updating the rects and texts:
https://bl.ocks.org/ckothari/699b112b6e1376779e65973bbabdced6